# Kibana/Lucene query: how to filter out requests by presense of a slash from Apache log?

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, lucene, logstash, kibana

I have uploaded Apache access logs of my website into Elasticsearch, connected Kibana with it and want to filter those log entries.

My logs contain 2 types of user requests (urls):

```
/search?q=foobar
```

and

```
/sequence-search?q=foobar
```

I want to make a Lucene query that returns requests of the first kind, but filters out the second kind.

I tried writing the following Lucene query, which doesn't work: `request:"\/search\?q\="`.

As you can see, I requested exact match and escaped the special characters. What's wrong?

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44982394/4604579

Comment: @Val Thank you so much, Val, I think, that's the answer, I was looking for.