# How to use slash ('/') in Kibana Discovery?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm testing ELK stack for nginx-access logs. It looks good except I have not found a way to search records in Kibana Discovery (v5.3.2) with a path that start with `"/test/a"`. Search works if I remove slashes, but in this case, I get what I don't need - `"/ololo/ololo?test=1"`

I tried different requests:

```
path:/\/test\/a/
path:/\\/test\\/a/
path:"/test/a"
path:"\/test\/a"
path:"\\/test\\/a"
```

but nothing works as I expect.

Records:

```
[
{
    ...
    "path": "/test/a1"
    ...
},
{
    ...
    "path": "/test/a2"
    ...
},
{
    ...
    "path": "/ololo/ololo?test=1"
    ...
},        
]
```

Mapping:

```
"path": {
  "type": "string", 
  "index": "analyzed", 
},
```

Is there any way to search using slashes as part of pattern?

**Update:**

These patterns do not work too:

```
path:/.*\/test\/a.*/
path:/[\/]test[\/]a/
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to change the mapping of the `path` field to not be analyzed, otherwise the slashes will not be indexed.

The mapping should be like this:

```
"path": {
  "type": "string", 
  "index": "not_analyzed",    <--- change this
},
```

Note that you need to delete your index and re-create it with the proper mapping in order for this to work.

After that you'll be able to search using the following query `path:"/test/a"`

Comment: It does not work. `path:"/test/a"` returns nothing, instead of records `/test/a1` and `/test/a2` . This works: `path:"/test/a1"` or `path:"/test/a2"`, but it's not what I need

Comment: Oh sorry I misread your question, I missed the fact that you needed to search for path prefixes. In this case, you should be able to search for `path:/test/a*` (without the double quotes). Give it a try.

Comment: `path:/test/a*` returns needed records (`/test/a1`, `/test/a2`), but also returns a lot of `/ololo?test=1`. Looks like this pattern return all records that contains word `test`

Comment: Let's try something more involved with a regular expression then. Try this: `path:/^\/test\/a.*/`

Comment: `path:/^\/test\/a.*/` - No results found.

Comment: `path:/.*test.*/`, `path:/test/` - returns needed and not needed records - all records that contain word `test`

Comment: Another question: have you refreshed your index pattern in Kibana after recreating your index?

Comment: Yes, it shows that `path` is `searchable` and `analyzed`

Comment: Then it is not correct, it should show that it is not analyzed since you've changed the mapping. Please refresh your index pattern.

Comment: It helped. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Use this query as example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "path.keyword"
      ],
      "query": "\\/test\\/a\\/*",
      "analyzer": "keyword",
      "analyze_wildcard": true
    }
  }
}
```